# How to get Google maps 3d building terrain for my project?

Tags: google-maps

TL;DR

How do I get Google maps 3d building terrain for my project?
They provides it?

I want to draw 3d buildings of my neighborhood on my project.
Ideally I wish I could do something on Web but App is Ok too.

For example
https://www.localize.city/address/new%20york/new%20york/manhattan/west%2047%20street/505/insights?itemIndex=0&itemOpen=false

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, [Maps Javascript API](https://www.google.com/url?q=https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial&sa=U&ved=0ahUKEwjNj5mdpuXhAhXkDaYKHYL3CfMQFggFMAA&client=internal-uds-cse&cx=005326727925058575645:u2hfjb_gpuk&usg=AOvVaw0dbxVk6jEBfV9ksAHm2vdT) doesn't have this feature, however, this can be done using the [Maps SDK for Android](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/intro) with [Camera and View](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/views), you may visit the documentation to further understand, you may also check the sample in this [repository](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-samples/blob/master/ApiDemos). Hope this helps.